# How to specify gdal_contour output format as postgresql table?

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, contour

I want to generate contours with gdal_contour command.
It generates an output as shapefile by default.
I want this utility to output a postgresql (postgis) table.

The documentation says there is a -f  option, but I couldn't find any examples on specifying a format.
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html

Can anyone provide an example of specifying postgis table as an output for gdal_contour?

Comment: The time you need to do this is when the generated SHP file exceeds the 2/4 GB limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved.
Just like in ogr2ogr:

```
gdal_contour -f PostgreSQL -i 1 -nln cont iamrast.tif "PG:host=localhost user=iampg password=iampgpass dbname=iamgis"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen `-f` option using as you too.

as a practical solution for loading output shapefile:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 -W latin5 -I -S -D contour.shp contours | psql -U postgres -h localhost -d mydatabase
```

beside this you can check out gdal extension on qgis how it formatting your command.(it shows gdal command in windows) at `Raster->Extraction->Contour` menu.